# Existence of antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on the open unit interval.
What assumptions you have to make about $f$ to be sure that it posseses an antiderivative?
I'm interested in the weakest (most general) possible assumptions, so some nontrivial equivalent condition would be optimal.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe there are (at least) two different questions. The weakest condition to have an antiderivative is to simply be a derivative, and there is a lot of literature on attempts to classify the property of being a derivative (in ways besides just restating "is a derivative"). See Andrew M. Bruckner's book **Differentiation of Real Functions** for an entry point into this area. The other question has to do with methods for obtaining an antiderivative, and for this various integration methods have been developed -- the Riemann integral, the Lebesgue integral, the Denjoy integral, etc.

Comment: My question is adressing precisely the first issue. The reference you mentioned is kind of thing  I was looking for, but I'm afaid I don't have acces to it. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In addition and maybe I'm not understanding fully, is it safe to say that if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, there exists another function $F$ which is differentiable on $(a,b)$ down to $f$? While continuity doesn't imply the function itself is differentiable, continuity does imply the existence of another function which is differentiable down to $f$?

Comment: @DWade64: Yes, given any continuous function $f$ defined on $(a,b),$ then there exists a function $F$ defined on $(a,b)$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for each $x \in (a,b).$ And you don't need advanced mathematical ideas for this such as Lebesgue integration and measure theory --- for continuous functions $f,$ the corresponding functions $F$ can be defined by using the Riemann integral. This is one half of the usual 2-part version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. See [Is every continuous function a derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550895)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the help as well as the answer you gave!

Comment: @DWade64: If f is continuous on the Real line ( at least a.e.) , then $F:= \int_0^x f $ is an antiderivative, and, wherever F is continuous, F'=f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in response to your reply to my comment.

Here are two useful expository papers that are freely available on the internet:

Andrew M. Bruckner, [*Derivatives: why they elude classification*](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/andrew-m-bruckner-derivatives-why-they-elude-classification.pdf), **Mathematics Magazine** 49 #1 (January 1976), 5-11. (curtsey of Andres Caicedo and google)

Andrew M. Bruckner, [*The problem of characterizing derivatives revisited*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1341343228), **Real Analysis Exchange** 22 #1 (1995-96), 112-133.

Answer (score -1):

For a simpler, more basic take, if f is a.e. continuous on the Real line, define:

$$F:= \int_0^x f(t)dt +C $$, where $C$ is a Real constant. Then , wherever f is continuous, $F'=f$

Edit: In order for a function f to be recovered as the integral of its derivative, i.e., to have $F= \int F', f $ must be Absolutely Continuous.

For a function f to be a derivative, i.e., the derivative of another function, it must satisfy the Darboux property.

Comment: And , do tell, downvote, just what is wrong with this?