# Is every continuous function a derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am pretty sure that this statement is true, altough I don't find the correct proof for it. I am pretty sure it involves using the Fundamental Thorem of Calculus, but again I can't seem to picture how to use it to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if every continuous function has an anti-derivative?

Comment: At the end of the day, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y) dy$ is well-defined for $x \in [a,b]$, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ for each $x \in [a,b]$. There are some technicalities here that may or may not matter for your purposes, such as the proof that every continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Offered merely as a curiosity:  Suppose one had studied derivatives but not integrals.  With a bit of skill you can prove this:  *If $f$ is a bounded function on an interval $[a,b]$ then there exists a Lipschitz function $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ at every point $x$ at which $f$ is continuous.*  It is easier, of course, to rely on the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus to do the work for you.

Answer (score 8):

This is word for word the exact statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$

Comment: Very nice :). To be fair, though, in my experience what most students think of as the fundamental theorem is a (to an undergraduate calculus student, much more useful) corollary: $``$If $f$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ in $[a,b]$, then
$$\int _a^bf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=F(b)-F(a)."$$ (Quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary).)