# Necessary conditions for a function to have an antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Given an interval $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a function $f : B \to \mathbb{R}$, what are the necessary conditions (if any) on $f$ in order for it to have an antiderivative? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Of_non-continuous_functions) lists some examples under the assumption that $B$ is an open interval. Are there any others? What if $B$ is not open?

Comment: In order to hace derivative at one point, you need to be as near as you want to that point. so $B$ must contain an open interval.

Comment: I did see a related Q on this site, with $B=\Bbb R$. The answers included numerous links to published papers. I got the impression that the answer is a "book" and is still not completed.

Comment: Related, and possibly what @DanielWainfleet was thinking of, is [Existence of antiderivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796292/existence-of-antiderivative).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro. Also on this site is the Q of whether a continuous $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ could be differentiable at each $q\in \Bbb Q$ but not on the irrationals.  Regrettably, the Answers addressed $ this$ Q instead. Do you anything on the types of subsets of $\Bbb R$ that can ( or can't  ) be the  set of points of differentiability of a continuous real function?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: See [Characterization of sets of differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905083), where the possible sets of differentiability is discussed rather thoroughly. See also: **(a)** my answer to [Monotone Function, Derivative Limit Bounded, Differentiable - 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746930); **(b)** my answer to [Construct a function on a bounded interval on $\Bbb{R}$ which is continuous everywhere but differentiable only at irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784334) and my comments to Charles Madeline's answer.